# Что выбрать при решении задачи, эффективность или краткость?

Tags: любой-язык

Предположим, стоит задача, реализовать которую можно используя как `A`, так и `B`. `A` эффективнее чем `B` но код, работающий с `B` выглядит проще, понятнее, короче.

Что же выбирать в работе?
И что использовать в задаче на собеседовании? Предположим, что задачу проще решить используя `B`, но я выбираю `A`. Что бы вы тогда обо мне подумали (если бы собеседовали)?

Comment: Цель. Это - основа выбора. Выпендриться на собеседовании? Создать приложение с максимальной эффективностью? с максимальной сопровождаемостью? что-то ещё? Какой будет цель - таким будет и решение.

Comment: Жаль, что вопрос хотят закрыть. Я бы хотел увидеть здесь ответы многих людей

Comment: *Я бы хотел увидеть здесь ответы многих людей* Уточните, что именно Вы попытались начать - опрос или холивар.

Comment: @Akina, именно опрос

Comment: По-моему, на SO.ru опросы - неформат.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А кто мешает на собеседовании показать оба варианта? Если, конечно, вы имеете дело с понимающим человеком, а не попкой, который смотрит в листик с "правильным" ответом.

А вообще - решение зависит от того, что за задача, зачем и т.д. Например, для одноразового запуска и получения каких-то данных нет смысла угробить полдня работы, чтоб сэкономить полчаса счета, например...

Мне кажется, что сначала нужно выбрать решение более понятное и короткое, и только если точно выяснится, что получившаяся производительность не устраивает - переходить к более сложному, но более эффективному решению.

Где там корень всех зол по Кнуту? В преждевременной оптимизации, не так ли? :)

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Вы указали только один критерий качества, производительность, я думаю тут может быть ещё и использование памяти, например

Comment: @StrangerintheQ И еще с десяток других :) Давайте назовем это *эффективностью* и не будем спорить...

Comment: Не спору ради, а чтобы у читающих ваш хороший ответ не сложилось однобокое впечатление

Comment: Просто если выбранный критерий качества это цена разработки, то все кардинально меняется, тогда и решение В заиграет новыми красками

Comment: Понял, на что вы намекаете, Пух :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ... или цена сопровождения... что порою как бы не поважнее будет.

Comment: К сожалению, иногда бизнес диктует правила, это так

Comment: Бизнес диктует свои правила: деньги дают тем у кого первого прога откомпайлится. А если вы второй, то не дадут - пашет пока...

Answer (score 1):

(Как человек, который провел много собеседований).

Самое главное на собеседовании - это показать, что Вы можете (да, ключевое слово можете) написать за приемлемое время более-менее рабочее решение. Вполне возможно, что это решение для компании будет очень классным, потому что будет решать задачу (хотя для перфекциониста оно будет *ужась-ужась*)

> Что же выбирать в работе?

Бизнесу нужно то, что работает и приносит прибыль. Если задачу можно написать за час, но она требует немного больше памяти (но она у нас есть) - ок, делаем решение, смотрим. Может через месяц этот код уже будет не нужен или поменяется задача.

> И что использовать в задаче на собеседовании? Предположим, что задачу проще решить используя B, но я выбираю A. Что бы вы тогда обо мне подумали (если бы собеседовали)?

Тут спрятано несколько вещей. Во первых, собеседуемый может не знать о A и B. А знать о C,D и E. И не факт, что его решения будут лучше и красивее. Во вторых, собеседующий может порасспрашивать дальше и вполне возможно, родятся новые решения.

Есть чудесное выступление [Кейт Грегори](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O50qTuM5OT0), где она рассказывает историю, о том, как один программист оптимизировал и переписывал код много раз, делая лучше, но... код все ещё не компилировался...

Comment: Спасибо) Кстати ссылка ломаная

Comment: ссылка уже нормальная. Я ее точно правильной вставлял. Видимо кто то (js) решил исправить:)